# Not displaying correct string/ value from switch statement after update and after build

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, next.js13

Problem - Nextjs app not displaying correct string/ value from switch statement after build

Not sure if this helps but this switch statement worked before I updated from Nextjs 12 to 14.

I have a function with a switch statement that formats price depending on country. For example, if locale is 'sv' I want to display "100 kr" but currently after build it's showing "100" without the price prefix in the UI. But when logging `console.log(process.env.locale)` in prod it gives me 'sv' and also when logging `console.log(`${formattedPrice} kr`)` it gives me correct string.

So it differs before/after build showing the correct string before but not after build. When logging the returned value it gives me the same thing no matter if locally or not but seems like the code executes different after build?

I've fixed it by removing the return statement outside the switch case and replace it with a default value inside the switch case which works. But I'm trying to understand what differs these switch cases?

Switch case 1 (works locally but not on PROD (after build):

```
switch (locale) {
  case 'sv':
    return `${formattedPrice} kr`;
  case 'nb':
    return `kr ${formattedPrice}`;
  case 'da':
    return `kr. ${formattedPrice}`;
  case 'fi':
    return `${formattedPrice} €`;
}

return formattedPrice;
```

Switch case 2 (the updated version, works locally and on PROD/ after build):

```
switch (locale) {
  case 'sv':
    return `${formattedPrice} kr`;
  case 'nb':
    return `kr ${formattedPrice}`;
  case 'da':
    return `kr. ${formattedPrice}`;
  case 'fi':
    return `${formattedPrice} €`;
  default:
    return formattedPrice;
}
```

Full code:

```
const formatPrice = (price: string | number) => {
  const locale = process.env.LOCALE;

  let roundedPrice = Number(price);

  if (roundedPrice % 1 != 0) {
    roundedPrice = Number(roundedPrice.toFixed(2));
  }

  let formattedPrice = String(roundedPrice);

  formattedPrice = formattedPrice.toString().replace('.', ',');

  if (
    formattedPrice.split(',') &&
    formattedPrice.split(',')[1] &&
    formattedPrice.split(',')[1].length < 2
  ) {
    formattedPrice = `${formattedPrice}0`;
  }

  switch (locale) {
    case 'sv':
      return `${formattedPrice} kr`;
    case 'nb':
      return `kr ${formattedPrice}`;
    case 'da':
      return `kr. ${formattedPrice}`;
    case 'fi':
      return `${formattedPrice} €`;
  }

  return formattedPrice;

};

export default formatPrice;
```

Comment: I think locale doesn't have any value in `sv`,`nb`,`da`,`fi`.

Comment: *"its showing "100" without the price prefix"* - Which suggests that `locale` didn't match any of the `case` values.  When you debugged the production code, what exact observed value did `locale` have?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add info about that. When I'm logging locale on PROD it gives me 'sv'. @David

Comment: Tested with different env variables and logged for all different countries and it gives me matching locale on PROD (sv, nb, da, fi). @Adrid